# Xamarin Forms: All device features available with USB Debugging?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

When using Xamarin forms (VS2017 for Windows) for cross-app development, there is certain features that are not covered by the android emulator, such as Bluetooth. Is this any different with USB debugging? Assuming my app runs via USB debugging on an actual mobile device, would Bluetooth be available in my running app as if it was installed and running natively?

I just would like to know, if I can test all features that are missing in the emulator by using USB debugging or is there any other limitations in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an actual device there are no limitations other than those imposed by the device itself.

Comment: Ok, then I can run the app on my phone while debugging concurrently inside Visual Studio using breakpoints, checking console output etc. Very nice, thanks!